# Failed to send Kubectl command to create deployment via SSM command

Tags: amazon-eks, kubectl, aws-ssm, aws-automation

I have an EKS cluster and i am trying to automate the process of creating a deployment-pod, accessing the pod using a terminal shell, running some commands within it and destroying the deployment.

i created a document with the commands, starting with creating a deployment-pod but doesn't seem to get pass the create deployment.

below is the command

```
 "kubectl create deployment --image=**********.dkr.ecr.ap-*****.amazonaws.com/csstatic0:1 testpod"
```

but i kept on getting this error

`The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`

I researched, and found adding the serviceAccountName in the command resolves the issue but still doesn't work.

I also created a YAML manifest with the serviceAccountName provided within but still got the same error.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: vulmelon
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: vulmelon
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: vulmelon
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: vulmelon
        image=**********.dkr.ecr.ap-*****.amazonaws.com/csstatic0:1 testpod
      serviceAccountName: default
```

What am I missing here?

your helps will be highly appreciated